# make rest api in nodejs for if not loged in

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, mongoose

I want an API for which if user is not logged in then redirect to `homepage /`
but this api is access by both web and android.

So i made like this for both web and app .

```
function requiresLogin(req, res, next) {
    if (req.session && req.session.userID) {
        return next();
    } else {
        res.send({status : "logout" , message : "Please Login First"});
    }
}
```

I don't understand how to redirect to `homepage /` by web-end

because If i am using `res.redirect('/homepage')` then what about app.

My ajax part is this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax(
        {
            success: function (result) {
                alert(alert.status);
                if (result.status === "logout") {
                    window.location = '/';
                }
                else {

                }
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
});
```

but nothing happens.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: @JonasW. but this `redirect` will not works for app like android.

Comment: On the client you check the response. Then you redirect. On the website, you run `window.location = "/homepage"`, and in the app you start the login activity. You do not use `res.redirect()`, because if this API is for both app and web, you'll only call it via AJAX.

Comment: @ChrisG I have edited my post, please check my ajax code.

Comment: Code works fine for me, what's the problem? (it's supposed to alert `result.status`, but the redirect should work nonetheless, it does for me; I also assume you've removed stuff from that `$.ajax` call, given that there's  no URL?)

Comment: when i tries to access any url without login ..it send `{"status":"logout","message":"Please Login First"}`  but not redirecting to homepage

Comment: Did you check the console for errors? When you fix the `alert()`, does it show `logout`?

Comment: i make an index.js file for ajax where i write ajax code.

Comment: Are you sure you're sending an AJAX request in the first place? Like I said, the above code is missing a URL. Read my comments or I will move on.

Comment: how to check for that? means am i sending an AJAX request or not.

Comment: it does't show any console in ajax.

Comment: FIX THE `alert`. And in case the client-side code you posted is your actual `$.ajax` call, IT DOESN'T HAVE A **URL**.